# Issues verifying signed data for Permit2

Tags: solidity, uniswap, signature, ecrecover

I'm trying to develop an end-to-end system using Uniswap's [Permit2](https://github.com/Uniswap/permit2/) (AllowanceTransfer).

To achieve that, after the Permit2 allowance, I have to sign a message and verify its integrity contract side. The signed message will consist of 3 elements: domain, types and values.

```typescript
const domain = {name: "Permit2", chainId: 5, verifyingContract: 0xPERMIT2ONGOERLI};

const types = {
      PermitSingle: [{ name: "details", type: "PermitDetails" }, { name: "spender", type: "address" }, { name: "sigDeadline", type: "uint256" }],
      PermitDetails: [{ name: "token", type: "address" },{ name: "amount", type: "uint160" },{ name: "expiration", type: "uint48" },{ name: "nonce", type: "uint48" }],
    };

const values = {
   details: {
        token: 0xDAI,
        amount: 1000 * 10^18,
        expiration: 168384570,
        nonce: 0,
      },
      spender: 0xMYCONTRACT,
      sigDeadline: 168384570,
};
```

I proceed to send this data to the signer's `signTypedData` utility (be it the one from ethers, wagmi etc.) and package it nicely as a parameter for my desired transaction, implemented in `0xMYCONTRACT`.

**The problem**

Within the signature verification flow of the [contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/permit2/blob/main/src/libraries/SignatureVerification.sol), `ecrecover` will return a totally unrelated address, clearly not the actual signer of the message (here, supposed to be `msg.sender`).

Has anyone dealt with a similar situation? If so, what's a possible fix for this signature mismatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved and proved to be nothing but an integration bug caused by an unclear contract API.

The values used to rebuild the hash (e.g. amount, nonce, token address) have to match 1:1 with the values included in the signature. As a suggestions, one should keep context specific values (e.g. amounts for transfers) separate from permit specific values (the max permitted amount from the signature).

Easiest way to do this: avoid abstracting the PermitSingle parameter logic in your own contract. Ask for a complete permit struct from the client that's separate from the rest of the contextual transaction details.